# Grails: async service in 1.3.7

Tags: grails, asynchronous, groovy

I have a mail service that uses mail plugin to send out notification. I have this triggered of the save method. What I have noticed is that the save method is now slower because part of the processing time is generating email template off the GSP and sending the message to the smtp host. 
What is the best strategy to speed up this proccess? I am thinking some kind of async processing. Are there facilities in Grails or Groovy that I can use (do I fall back to threads...?).

Comment: good point! will fork the plugin and add that func to it! cheers!

Comment: excellent idea, to be frank I am surprised it's not part of the core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several alternatives for async processing in Grails. I ended using the Executor plugin for the exact same use-case as you and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. One thing I can't figure out is if the plugin allows for non-blocking callbacks. I see the Future object blocks on get(). Any code samples would be much appreciated.